# figma union selection

Tags: figma

I'm trying to joint all the rectangles that I use to create this [image] so I use the union selection but I have this [image]
Is there a way to union all these rectangles but with keeping there color ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to make a group.  A union operation won't do what you want. Instead, select all the pieces and Group them.  Once grouped, you will be able to move the group around as though it was one unified object.  Try that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to union all the rectangles and have them maintain their original colors.

When you create a union of multiple vectors, you are combining them into a single vector. This single vector can only have one fill color applied to it. That's why the result is all blue.

If you want to treat these objects as a single object but have them maintain their individual colors, put them in a [frame](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041539473-Frames-in-Figma).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
**You need to group them ⌘G.**

After that, you can change it or download it if you need it.
Figma materials - https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039832054-Frames-and-Groups

Answer (score 0):

How about use the "Flatten selection" feature?
It will merge all shapes but keep the colors of all vectors.

[image: flatten selection]